# Count unique value with 2 criteria from 2 row

Tags: excel, count

Can you help me to solve this problem?

I have two row with different value each row like this:

[image]

I want to count how many city with name `london` but only count if the Name if different, so from the table above the result count is only 2 `london`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pivot table as a step to help:

1. Select the data and set up the pivot table:

   [image]
2. Change the design of the table to set:

   a. Report layout to tabular form

   b. Report layout to repeat all item labels

   c. Subtotals - do not show them

   then the pivot table should be like this:

   [image]
3. Finally, you can use `COUNTIF`. In my example, I have put the city name in G2 and referencing it in the formula:

   ```
   =COUNTIF(D:D,G2)
   ```

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You first need to group both columns

`=COUNTIF(UNIQUE(A2:B14),"london")`

**COUNTIF** count cells based on one criteria

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I want to count how many city with value " London" but from diffrent name. ex : don, london ; don, london ( cont = 1 ). don, london ; den, london ( count = 2 )

Comment: This answer should include a disclaimer about the current availability of the [UNIQUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e). ***Note: September 24, 2018: The UNIQUE function is one of several beta features, and currently only available to a portion of Office Insiders at this time. We'll continue to optimize these features over the next several months. When they're ready, we'll release them to all Office Insiders, and Office 365 subscribers.***.